# Parse HTML file using Perl

Tags: html, perl, parsing

I am trying extract the table inside this html file using perl.

I have tried this:

```
my $te = HTML::TableExtract->new();
$te->parse_file($g_log);
print "=====TE: $te ======\n";
```

Output is :

```
HTML:TableExtract = Hash(0x266f5f)
```

I tried iterating through $te and nothing found. Can anyone guide what to do next. I am new to this.

This is the HTML file:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math"
          xmlns:testng="http://testng.org">
       <head xmlns="">
          <title>TestNG Results</title>
          <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta>
          <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"></meta>
          <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0"></meta>
          <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache"></meta>
          <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-store"></meta>
          <LINK rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></LINK>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
       </head>
       <body>
          <h2>Test suites overview</h2>


<table width="100%">
                 <tr>
                    <td align="center" id="chart-container"><script type="text/javascript">
                                            renderSvgEmbedTag(600, 200);
                                        </script></td>
                 </tr>
              </table>

   </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::TableExtract;
my $filename = "testfile.html";
my $te = HTML::TableExtract->new();
$te->parse_file($filename);
foreach $ts ($te->tables) {
   print "Table found at ", join(',', $ts->coords), ":\n";
   foreach $row ($ts->rows) {
      print "   ", join(',', @$row), "\n";
   }
}
```

Note that `HTML::TableExtract` can also be invoked in ['tree' mode](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TableExtract#NOTES-ON-TREE-EXTRACTION-MODE) where the resulting HTML and extracted tables are encoded in `HTML::Element` tree structures.

`use HTML::TableExtract 'tree';`

Comment: I tried the written code and it worked. Make sure that the path to HTML file is correct.

Comment: Plus 1 Good. @ChankeyPathak

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are wanting to get out of the table. But I would strongly recomend using data dumper to look inside the hash.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::TableExtract;
use Data::Dumper;

my $html = <<'EOT';
<html xmlns="http://w...content-available-to-author-only...3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:math="http://e...content-available-to-author-only...t.org/math"
          xmlns:testng="http://t...content-available-to-author-only...g.org">
       <head xmlns="">
          <title>TestNG Results</title>
          <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta>
          <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"></meta>
          <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0"></meta>
          <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache"></meta>
          <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-store"></meta>
          <LINK rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></LINK>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
       </head>
       <body>
          <h2>Test suites overview</h2>


<table width="100%">
                 <tr>
                    <td align="center" id="chart-container"><script type="text/javascript">
                                            renderSvgEmbedTag(600, 200);
                                        </script></td>
                 </tr>
              </table>

    </table>
   </body>
  </html>
EOT

my $te = HTML::TableExtract->new();
$te->parse($html);

print Dumper($te);
```

Comment: Thanks! I saw the data through the dumper and I see this: '_tables' => {}